# CTE with temporary tables in Function

Tags: sql-server, common-table-expression

```
Create FUNCTION [dbo].[GetAllChildSpaces] 
(
    @CustomSpaceId varchar(40),
    @Userid int 
)
RETURNS NVARCHAR(MAX)
AS
BEGIN   
    DECLARE @Totalspace NVARCHAR(MAX)
    DECLARE  @tblTotalSpace table (CustomSpaceId NVARCHAR(40))

    WITH Hierachy (CustomSpaceId) AS 
     ( 
     SELECT  CustomSpaceId FROM  CV_CustomSpace e 
     UNION ALL 
     SELECT  e1.CustomSpaceId FROM  CV_CustomSpace e1 INNER JOIN Hierachy p  ON e1.ParentID = p.CustomSpaceId 
     ) 

  INSERT INTO @tblTotalSpace (CustomSpaceId)

  SET @Totalspace=( 
      SELECT STUFF((SELECT ',' + CAST(CustomSpaceId as varchar(50)) 
      FROM @tblTotalSpace FOR XML PATH('')) ,1,1,'') AS TotalSpaceID
  )

  DROP TABLE @tblTotalSpace

  return @Totalspace  
 END
```

I'm getting an error:

> Incorrect syntax near the keyword `'with'`. If this statement is a
>   common table expression, an xmlnamespaces clause or a change tracking
>   context clause, the previous statement must be terminated with a
>   semicolon.

Can any one solve this issue?

Comment: You have to prepend the `WITH` statement with a `;`

Comment: It tells you how to resolve the problem in the error message...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Terminate the previous statement with a semicolon

```
Create FUNCTION [dbo].[GetAllChildSpaces] ( @CustomSpaceId varchar(40), @Userid int ) RETURNS NVARCHAR(MAX) AS BEGIN
DECLARE @Totalspace NVARCHAR(MAX) 
DECLARE @tblTotalSpace table (CustomSpaceId NVARCHAR(40)); -- Here

WITH Hierachy (CustomSpaceId) AS 
...
```

For consistency and clarity, it doesn't hurt to terminate all statements with a semicolon.

Answer (score 1):

put a semicolon bofore WITH

```
;with  Hierachy (CustomSpaceId) AS 
 ( .............
```